# Flutter Unable to build for IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I am using `flutter 2.10.3` I have created a new project i was able to run on `simulator iphone 8` but when i run `flutter build ios` i am getting below error.

```
    The following build commands failed:
                CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'vibration' from project 'Pods')
                Ld

/Users/bilalrabbi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqtwcanhgaiurgblzcjnjgoffipl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences_ios.buil
                d/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/shared_preferences_ios normal armv7 (in target 'shared_preferences_ios' from project 'Pods')
               (2 failures)
```

and

```
[ +320 ms] Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

[   +6 ms] Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter
```

I have removed pod files. delete derived data. update pod cache but nothing seems to work. When i try to build again i am getting this error
Here is my PodFile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end


   


   post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
      build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end
```

I  also tried with `platform :ios, '11.0'`

Answer (score 0):

try deleting flutter SDK and re-install it
then run these commands in the project folder

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
```

then switch to the ios folder and run

```
pod install
```

Now try to build.

Comment: this didn't help.